# No response from stdout Hackerrank (python)

Tags: python

The program is supposed to take 3 numbers as arguments and return the root with the largest absolute value rounded to the nearest integer and in case they have the same absolute value return the positive root, however nothing outputs even if i change the command to return.

```
def findBiggerRoot(a, b, c):

    root1 = (-b+math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*(a*c))))/(2*a)
    root2 = (-b-math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*(a*c))))/(2*a)

    if abs(root1) > abs(root2):
        print (round(root1))
    elif root1 > root2:
        print (round(root1))    
    else:
        print (round(root2))
```

Comment: I suggest that you read through any convenient tutorial on using functions.  You have no output because you never called the function.  A tutorial will clear up this issue and several more that you haven't yet encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a function doesn't give any output.
Only if you call the function and execute the `print` in it, it will give an output to stdout.

On most programming contest platforms, you have to make sure that the functions get called. And also that you read the input from stdin.

E.g. by adding the following (assuming Python 3) to the end of your code.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b, c = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
    findBiggerRoot(a, b, c)
```